# Using R, if values in either variable A or B are 'NA', to then use values in variables C and D instead?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to calculate the mean of two variables and outputting it as a new variable. For example:

```
data$Average <- (data$Visit1 + data$Visit2) / 2
```

However, there are NA values for both 'Visit 1' and 'Visit 2' variables across the dataset.

How can I write some code such that I am able to identify if NA values exist in *either* Visit 1 or 2, then I would use the corresponding row's values but for 'Visit 3' and 'Visit 4' instead, to calculate the average? And if 'Visit 3' and 'Visit 4' values were NA, to use 'Visit 5' and 'Visit 6' instead?

Basically, the priority is to use Visits 1 and 2 data, but if those do not exist (NA), to use   Visits 3 and 4, and finally, last priority being Visits 5 and 6.

Many thanks!

Comment: I would use `rowMeans(data[c("Visit1", "Visit2")], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: This unfortunately does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()` from `dplyr`. `coalesce()` will use the first non-missing value at each position. I think this has better readability than `ifelse()` or `case_when()`.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    Average = coalesce(
      as.numeric((data$Visit1 + data$Visit2) / 2),
      as.numeric((data$Visit3 + data$Visit4) / 2),
      as.numeric((data$Visit5 + data$Visit6) / 2)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option for your edited question using `dplyr::case_when` to filter through the possibilities:

```
library(dplyr)

data$Average <- case_when(!is.na(data$Visit1) & !is.na(data$Visit2) ~ 
                                        (data$Visit1 + data$Visit2) / 2,
                          !is.na(data$Visit3) & !is.na(data$Visit4) ~ 
                                        (data$Visit3 + data$Visit4) / 2,
                          TRUE ~ (data$Visit1 + data$Visit2) / 2)
```

This is like `ifelse` but can handle more than 2 cases.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do multiple `ifelse` statements is with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- dat %>%
   mutate(
     average = case_when(
     !is.na(Visit1) & !is.na(Visit2) ~ (Visit1 + Visit2)/2,
     !is.na(Visit3) & !is.na(Visit4) ~ (Visit3 + Visit4)/2,
     !is.na(Visit5) & !is.na(Visit6) ~ (Visit5 + Visit6)/2,
     TRUE ~ NA
     )
   )
```

The advantages to this approach are: a) uses `tidyverse` and applicable to many cases of multiple `ifelse` statements, b) is easy to understand when you come back to the code later, c) use NA if some rows do not satisfy your conditions (i.e., TRUE ~ NA)

More documentation on `case_when` is here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html